# Can the injection tactic modify the end goal, or add extraneous assumptions?

Tags: coq, ltac

Consider the following development, an isolated part of [Adam Chlipala's `simplHyp`](http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/hritcu/dyn/coind/CpdtTactics.html):

```
(** Fail if H is in context *)
Ltac notInCtx H := assert H; [ assumption | fail 1 ] || idtac.

Ltac injectionInCtx :=
  match goal with
  (* Is matching on G strictly necessary? *)
  | [ H : ?F ?X = ?F ?Y |- ?G ] =>
    (* fail early if it wouldn't progress *)
    notInCtx (X = Y); 
    injection H;
    match goal with
      (* G is used here *)
      | [ |- X = Y -> G ] =>
        try clear H; intros; try subst
    end
  end.

Goal forall (x y : nat), S x = S y -> x = y.
  intros x y H.
  injectionInCtx.
  exact eq_refl.
Qed.
```

See the comments inline - `G` is matched at the outset, and eventually used to verify that the end goal remains the same. Is this to preclude the possibility that `injection H` might modify the goal or add extraneous assumptions?

Comment: `injection` does [modify the goal](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.injection): "the tactic derives the equality of all the subterms at positions where they differ and **adds them as antecedents to the conclusion of the current goal**."

Comment: Right, my wording is incorrect but I don't know how to do better. My point is, can the pattern `| [ |- X = Y -> G ] =>` ever fail to match?

Comment: Sure, `Goal forall l n, cons n l = cons 0 nil -> n = 0.
  intros l n H.
  injection H.
  Undo.
  Fail injectionInCtx.
Abort.`

Comment: For the versions of Coq I have tested, this last example fails at the first match, not at the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can modify `G`, but you can craft an hypothesis from which `injection` will generate more than one equality.

We define `injectionInCtx2` which is identical to `injectionInCtx` except that it does not use `G`.

```
Ltac injectionInCtx2 :=
  match goal with
  | [ H : ?F ?X = ?F ?Y |- _ ] =>
    (* fail early if it wouldn't progress *)
    notInCtx (X = Y);
    injection H;
    match goal with
    | [ |- X = Y -> _ ] =>
      try clear H; intros; try subst
    end
  end.

Definition make_pair {A} (n:A) := (n, n).

Goal forall (x y : nat), make_pair x = make_pair y -> x = y.
Proof.
  intros x y H.
  (* [injection H] gives [x = y -> x = y -> x = y] *)
  Fail injectionInCtx.
  injectionInCtx2.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```